# Using Linq to Sql join in generic handler

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, handler

I have some query that is working correctly but I just copied exact code without any modification to a new Generic Handler (ashx) file and I'm getting an error. This is the code:

```
 System.Collections.Generic.List<ChartPrice> ChartPrices =
 new System.Collections.Generic.List<ChartPrice>();
 using (DatabaseDataContext db = new DatabaseDataContext())
    {
       ChartPrices = (from p1 in db.Prices
                     join p2 in db.Prices on p1.Date equals p2.Date
                     where p1.ProductId == -1 && p1.Id != p2.Id
                     orderby p1.Date descending
                     select new ChartPrice {
                     Price1 = p1.Amount.ToString(),
                     Price2 = p2.Amount.ToString(),
                     Date = (DateTime)p1.Date })
                     .Take(30).ToList();
    }
```

And this is the error:

> Error  33  Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Data.Linq.Table'.  'Join' not found.  Are you missing a reference or a using directive for 'System.Linq'?

I get a red line under the first db.Prices (`ChartPrices = (from p1 in db.Prices`)

[image]

Is there something I can do to use this code in generic handler file?

Comment: What datatype is ChartPrices? ChartPrices may not be able hold the end result, im trying to recreate the problem but i cannot figure out the data type used.

Comment: It's `List<ChartPrice>`. If that was the issue, wouldn't the red line be under the `select` or `ToList()` calls?

Comment: its a custom class and as I said in another page I just getting the results and generating a table and a chart. I just want to use the same code in a generic handle file to generate a csv version of it for download. the code works in the other page

Comment: @JRLambert chart price is a list let me add it to the code, as it causes confusion

Comment: I just uploaded a screen shot of the code

Comment: Does `db.Prices` implements `IEnumerable<T>`? And Are you using `System.Linq`?

Comment: @Satpal if you read my comment the same code work in another page there must be some problem with a reference or something like that. there is no problem with code or datatypes as it works in other page of the same project

Comment: Just check once at the top, I think you are missing namesapce usage `using System.Linq`

Comment: it has something to do with generic handler file

Comment: if it's not too much could you post the class for ChartPrices, there is not that much to work for except what Satpal suggested check if you have used the namespace  `System.Linq`.

Comment: @CallumCarmicheal you were right but I thought it would just give me error for all the query if it was for that. Thanks a lot  the problem is solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base class does not include/use `System.Linq` so linq expressions were not applicable for usage in code.

Note: this was solved in the comments, this answer is just for those that did not read the comments.